# changed migration class name, now migrations fail

Tags: laravel, migration

I tried running `composer dump-autoload` and after that run migrate and got this error

> Class 'CreateContentTemplateBlocksTable' not found

I renamed the file into `'CreateTemplateBlocksTable'`.
Why is laravel still looking for the old file name? Is there cache somewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the migration class name to match, and then re-run `composer dump-autoload`. If that doesn't work, go to

> vendor\composer\autoload_static.php

to change the name here as well.

The last place to check is your DB, which creates a table for all of your migrations (that's the table name). Edit the necessary names here as well.

Comment: @maxit, No problem!

Comment: The hint with the database table was very helpful, thank you!